# Save.php "NO Data Received"

Tags: php, mysql, database

when i want to save data to database using save.php button then my browser show NO Data Received and data not saved in database?

```
    <?php

include 'database.php';

$nama = $_POST['nama'];
$jalan = $_POST['jalan'];
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lng = $_POST['lng'];
$deskripsi = $_POST['deskripsi'];


$kueri = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wisata (nama, jalan, lat, lng, deskripsi) VALUES ('$nama', '$jalan', '$lat', '$lng','$deskripsi');");
if($kueri){
    echo "Data berhasil disimpan<br>
    <a href=\"index.php\">Kembali</a>";
}  else {
    echo "Data gagal disimpan<br>
    <a href=\"index.php\">Kembali</a>";
}

?>
```

something wrong?

Comment: How are you calling this code? What debugging have you done - does this code receive the values OK, but the query fails, or does it get no data at all?

Comment: <form method="post" action="save.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> is that right?

Comment: It looks like it should be - could you edit your question, and add the form into it, please?

Comment: Why there is semicolon is sql query statement?

Comment: how to fix this simpan button?
http://semarangsig.tk/wisata/tambah.php

Answer (score 0):

Hosting was attacked by DDOS and that Database is broken